# In this case, are 'in' and 'during' interchangeable?

Tags: prepositions

> It keeps the house at a comfortable temperature **during** the hot day.
> The soil absorbs heat **in** the hot daytime hours.

Can I say "***in** the hot day*" and "***during** the hot daytime hours*"?

Comment: In those contexts, you can say, "***during** the hot daytime hours*", but you cannot say, "***in** the hot day*". My best guess about why is it's how the individual nouns correlate with the prepositions, rather than a general rule you can learn, but I'm not confident enough to put that in an answer.

Comment: I agree with @gotube. What you **could** say, however, is “in the hot days of summer.” Also possible are “in the heat of the day,” or (even better) “in the heat of a summer day.”